# Managing <iframe> in a jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, iframe, coffeescript

i have a navbar which has four link , onclick any link the respective page opens up in a frame below the navbar, but when i use right click open in new tab i want the entire page to be opened ie opening a particular link alone in a new tab should not be allowed

Links should be opened or displayed in the frame alone and not separately. can this be done ?

```
 <a href="page1.jsp" target="frame1">page1</a>
 <a href="page2.jsp" target="frame1">page2</a>
 <iframe name="frame1" src="page3.jsp">
```

right clicking on the link and opening in new window should launch the entire application again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each page that should only be shown in the iframe (page1.jsp, page2.jsp, and page3.jsp) should include JS to detect whether or not it's being displayed in its own window. For example, if the page with the iframe is index.jsp, page1.jsp should include this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (top.location.href == self.location.href)
  // Redirect user to main page, passing current page name:
  top.location.href = 'index.jsp?frame=page1';
//-->
</script>
```

Then, inside index.jsp you should cause the src of your iframe to load the indicated frame source:

```
<% 
// Establish default source:
String frame_src = 'page3.jsp';
// Establish controlled list of pages to show in the iframe (important to be restrictive)
String[] allowed_srcs = ['page1','page2','page3'];
// Get targeted frame from query string, if given:
String targeted_frame = request.getParameter('frame');
if(Arrays.asList(allowed_srcs).contains(targeted_frame))
  frame_src = targeted_frame + '.jsp';
%>
<iframe name="frame1" src="<%= frame_src %>"></iframe>
```